# copying an image onto another with JOCL/OpenCL

Tags: java, image-processing, gpu, opencl, jocl

so my goal is to use the GPU for my brand new Java project which is to create a game and the game engine itself (I think it is a very good way to learn in deep how it works).

**I was using multi-threading on the CPU with java.awt.Graphics2D to display my game, but i have observed on other PCs that the game was running below 40FPS so i have decided to learn how to use GPU** (I will be still rendering all objects in a for loop then draw the image on screen).

**For that reason, I started to code following the OpenCL documentation and the JOCL samples a small simple test which is to paint the texture onto the background image** (let's amdit that every entities has a texture).

**This method is called in each render call and it is given the background, the texture, and the position of this entity as arguments.**

*Both codes below has been updated to fit @ProjectPhysX recommandations.*

```
public static void XXX(final BufferedImage output_image, final BufferedImage input_image, float x, float y) {
        cl_image_format format = new cl_image_format();
        format.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
        format.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT8;

        //allocate ouput pointer
        cl_image_desc output_description = new cl_image_desc();
        output_description.buffer = null; //must be null for 2D image
        output_description.image_depth = 0; //is only used if the image is a 3D image
        output_description.image_row_pitch = 0; //must be 0 if host_ptr is null
        output_description.image_slice_pitch = 0; //must be 0 if host_ptr is null
        output_description.num_mip_levels = 0; //must be 0
        output_description.num_samples = 0; //must be 0
        output_description.image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D;
        output_description.image_width = output_image.getWidth();
        output_description.image_height = output_image.getHeight();
        output_description.image_array_size = output_description.image_width * output_description.image_height;

        cl_mem output_memory = clCreateImage(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, format, output_description, null, null);
        
        //set up first kernel arg
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(output_memory));
        
        //allocates input pointer
        cl_image_desc input_description = new cl_image_desc();
        input_description.buffer = null; //must be null for 2D image
        input_description.image_depth = 0; //is only used if the image is a 3D image
        input_description.image_row_pitch = 0; //must be 0 if host_ptr is null
        input_description.image_slice_pitch = 0; //must be 0 if host_ptr is null
        input_description.num_mip_levels = 0; //must be 0
        input_description.num_samples = 0; //must be 0
        input_description.image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D;
        input_description.image_width = input_image.getWidth();
        input_description.image_height = input_image.getHeight();
        input_description.image_array_size = input_description.image_width * input_description.image_height;

        DataBufferInt input_buffer = (DataBufferInt) input_image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        int input_data[] = input_buffer.getData();

        cl_mem input_memory = clCreateImage(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, format, input_description, Pointer.to(input_data), null);

        //loads the input buffer to the gpu memory
        long[] input_origin = new long[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        long[] input_region = new long[] { input_image.getWidth(), input_image.getHeight(), 1 };
        int input_row_pitch = input_image.getWidth() * Sizeof.cl_uint; //the length of each row in bytes
        clEnqueueWriteImage(commandQueue, input_memory, CL_TRUE, input_origin, input_region, input_row_pitch, 0, Pointer.to(input_data), 0, null, null);
        
        //set up second kernel arg
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(input_memory));

        //set up third and fourth kernel args
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, Sizeof.cl_float, Pointer.to(new float[] { x }));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, Sizeof.cl_float, Pointer.to(new float[] { y }));
        
        //blocks until all previously queued commands are issued
        clFinish(commandQueue);

        //enqueue the program execution
        long[] globalWorkSize = new long[] { input_description.image_width, input_description.image_height };
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, null, globalWorkSize, null, 0, null, null);

        //transfer the output result back to host
        DataBufferInt output_buffer = (DataBufferInt) output_image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        int output_data[] = output_buffer.getData();
        long[] output_origin = new long[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        long[] output_region = new long[] { output_description.image_width, output_description.image_height, 1 };
        int output_row_pitch = output_image.getWidth() * Sizeof.cl_uint;
        clEnqueueReadImage(commandQueue, output_memory, CL_TRUE, output_origin, output_region, output_row_pitch, 0, Pointer.to(output_data), 0, null, null);

        //free pointers
        clReleaseMemObject(input_memory);
        clReleaseMemObject(output_memory);
    }
```

And here's the program source runned on the kernel.

const sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

```
__kernel void drawImage(__write_only image2d_t dst_image, __read_only image2d_t src_image, float xoff, float yoff)
{
    const int x = get_global_id(0);
    const int y = get_global_id(1);

    int2 in_coords = (int2) { x, y };

    uint4 pixel = read_imageui(src_image, sampler, in_coords);
    pixel = -16184301;
    printf("%d, %d, %u\n", x, y, pixel);

    const int sx = get_global_size(0);
    const int sy = get_global_size(1);

    int2 out_coords = (int2) { ((int) xoff + x) % sx, ((int) yoff + y) % sy};
    
    write_imageui(dst_image, out_coords, pixel);
}
```

Without the call to write_imageui, the background is painted black, otherwhise it is white.
At the moment, I am a bit struggling to understand why pixel = 0 in the C function, but i think that someone familiar with JOCL would found out very quick my error in this code. I am very confused with this code for today, maybe tomorrow, but i don't feel like I will ever catch myself my mistake. For that reason i request your help to review my code. I feel like an idiot that i can't figure it out at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```c
    const int sx = get_global_size(0);
    const int sy = get_global_size(1);
    int2 out_coords = (int2) { (xoff + x)%sx, (yoff + y)%sy};
```

to avoid errors or undefined behaviour. Right now you are writing into Nirwana if the coordinate+offset is putside the image region. Also there is no `clEnqueueWriteImage` before the kernel is called, so `src_image` on the GPU is undefined and may contain random values.

OpenCL requires kernel parameters to be declared in `global` memory space:

```c
__kernel void drawImage(global image2d_t dst_image, global image2d_t src_image, global float xoff, global float yoff)
```

Also as someone who has written a graphics engine in Java, C++ and GPU-parallelized in OpenCL, let me give you some guidance: In the Java code, you probably use painter's algorithm: Make a list of all drawn objects with their approximate z-coordinates, sort the objects by z-coordinate and draw them back-to-front in a single for-loop. On the GPU, painter's algorithm won't work as you cannot parallelize it. Instead you have a list of objects (lines/triangles) in 3D space, and you parallelize over this list: Each GPU thread rasterizes a single triangle, all threads at the same time, and draw the pixels on the frame at the same time. To solve the draing order problem, you use a z-buffer: an image consisting of a z-coordinate per pixel. During rasterization of the line/triange, you calculate the z-coordinate for every pixel, and only if it is larger than the one previously in the z-buffer at that pixel, you draw the new color.

Regarding performance: java.awt.Graphics2D is very efficient in terms of CPU usage, you can do ~40k triangles per frame at 60fps. With OpenCL, expect ~30M triangles per frame at 60fps.

Comment: Thx a lot for the quick respond @ProjectPhysX (and the advices on writting a game engine), I will test it later. I don't think that I have understood all of it, but you put me back on the right track.

Atm, I have a scene that maps z-index to a collection of objects (i must also have ommited that it will be a 2d engine only so every entity is rectangle for the moment).

Comment: **UPDATE** I'v updated my code to match your suggestions. I added the c lines to avoid errors as you told me to do and clEnqueueWriteImage before the call of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel like : ` clEnqueueWriteImage(commandQueue, input, true, new long[] {0, 0, 0}, new long[] {texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), 1}, 0, (long) 0, Pointer.to(inputData), 0, null, null); `
I still issue the same behaviour, pixel = 0 even after pixel = -16184301 which is surprising to me. 
Tbh more than my ocl skill, my english is limiting my understanding. I need some clarification. Would be very helpful.

Comment: I just found another possible cause for the error: Are you missing `clCreateKernel` before the first call to `clSetKernelArg`? If `kernel` is not initialized before `clSetKernelArg`, it won't work.

Comment: I have created the kernel once in a method above called when I init my application. That is not enough to call it multiple time after ? You are right in fact, all the args equal zero, there might be something wrong here.

Comment: Ok that's fine then. Once the `kernel` is created and kernel arguments are linked, you can call it as many times as required. But all arguments being zero is strange nevertheless. I can't make out the definitive cause yet.

Comment: I have updated the source code in my post to match your responds, can you take a look one last time ?

Comment: I see what's wrong, or at least part of it. `pixel` is type `uint4`. You cannot print `pixel` as `uint`, but only its components `pixel.x`, `pixel.y`, `pixel.z`, `pixel.w`. You also cannot write a signed integer to `pixel`, but only unsigned integers to the components. Also keep in mind the range of the colors. For example: `pixel.x = 255;` will set the red component to its maximum value.

Comment: You got it right, pixel.x gives a value for the red in range of 0-255 ! That helps me a lot. But still xoff and yoff are equal to zero for no obvious reason to me, I'll try to debug this this afternoon.

Comment: In your kernel parameters, you are missing the global keyword for each parameter. change it to `global image2d_t dst_image, global image2d_t src_image, global float xoff, global float yoff`.

Comment: I have never seen global global args in jocl samples, neither clWriteImage but that makes sens. In SimpleImage it is like this __kernel void rotateImage(__read_only image2d_t sourceImage, __write_only image2d_t targetImage, float angle). Plus i have an error when i write global in my project...